# What is the better way to resolve anti-aliasing in babylon.js?

Tags: javascript, optimization, game-development, babylonjs

I am building 3d web game with `babylon.js`.

I faced the bad rendering issue.

So I tried to assign `postprocess` to camera for enhancement of rendering.

```
new BABYLON.PassPostProcess("scale_pass", 2.0, camera, BABYLON.Texture.LINEAR_LINEAR_MIPNEAREST);
```

Rendering quality was enhanced.

But I have faced another issue.

This way consume more GPU and Memory.

I think this can't be best solution.

I want to know the better way to enhance rendering quality and optimize the scene.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello did you make sure to turn antialiasing on on your engine?

with:

```
var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true):
```

Comment: Frankly, I used react-babylonjs. So I tried to set props `antialias={true}` and it worked.

Comment: Hi, I use `enableEdgesRendering` in box mesh, but it doesn't antialias. Do you have any idea? Thanks